# how to filter record according to current date in codeigniter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

In my model class firstly i used query as follows.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM todaywork WHERE idEmployee = $user")
```

but now i want to get data filtering as the current date. i used 'curdate()' for this. in wamp server i got the result what i want. but after putting this to model class in same place i can't get the data. what is the problem?

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM todaywork WHERE idEmployee = $user AND T_date = CURDATE()")
```

in here i used js function to go to controller class. this is my js function

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'today_list',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
          var datas = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
            datas.push('<tr id="list2' + x + '">'
                    + '<td hidden="true">' + result[x].idCustomer+ '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + result[x].C_name + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + result[x].F_itemname + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_trdate + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_trgrossrental + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">'
                    + '</td>'
            + '<td align="center">'
                    + '<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning " value="view">'

                    + '</td>'
                    + '</tr>');


                }

         $("#today_work").html(datas+"");
      //alert(datas);


    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('error');
    }
});

 }
```

then my controller class will be

```
 public function today_list(){
 $this->load->model('todayWork/todayWork_model');
 try{

   echo json_encode($this->todayWork_model->treport_getall());
 }
 catch(Exception $exc){
             return $exc->getTraceAsString();
 }  

 }
```

this direct to my model function which returns data from my database

```
function treport_getall()
{
    $user = $this->session->userdata['id'];

    //**********************************************
   try {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM todaywork WHERE idEmployee = $user");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           $row = $query->row(); 

               $from = $row->T_frange;
               $to = $row->T_trange;
               $note = $row->T_note;
        }     
               $this->db->select("cus.idCustomer,cus.C_name,f.F_itemname,ctr.*");
                //$whereCondition = array('cus.idCustomer' => $_POST['custId']);
                $this->db->where('C_trnoofarr >', $from);
                $this->db->where('C_trnoofarr <', $to);
                //filter where
                $this->db->from('customer cus');
                $this->db->join('contracts AS ctr', 'cus.idCustomer = ctr.idCustomer', 'INNER');
                $this->db->join('facility AS f','ctr.idContracts = f.idContracts','INNER');
                $query = $this->db->get();

                return $query->result();

     } catch (Exception $exc) {
               return $exc->getTraceAsString();
     }

}
```

before i using current date i get the result what i suppose to want. but after adding current date in where clause i get the error i put in error function in js file. how i solve my problem? please help me.

Comment: whats the error or output

Comment: show the complete code what have u tried